# Коряво отображаются слова сайта в Windows Phone

Tags: php

Собственно такая проблема: захожу на сайт через WP и все слова корявые. Хотя с `ios`, с `android` и компьютера отображается нормально.

[image]

Comment: Шрифт на телефоне есть в русской раскладке тот который используется на сайте?

Comment: Да, плюс поменял на стандартные всё равно такой тупняк

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте в какой кодировке сохранены страницы сайта.
Укажите ее явно в коде страницы:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  ...
```

Укажите в стилях альтернативные шрифты:

```
{ font-family: Verdana Franklin Gothic Medium; }
```

Comment: Да, кодировку стоит проверить. Рекомендую писать всегда в UTF-8 и проверять заголовки. И на сервере тоже проверить конфиги стоит. Если в одном месте где то разногласия по кодировке будут, может опять такая история приключится!
Еще, если данные берутся из БД, то стоит и там проверить кодировку.

Comment: Нет всё перепроверил всё равно так

Comment: Хоть какой-нибудь русскоязычный ресурс отображается на данном устройстве? Посмотрите какая кодировка используется. Как проверяли кодировку самих файлов своего проекта?